# Upgrading php on Mac mavericks with brew

Tags: php, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I am having issues when trying to upgrade php on OSX Mavericks. I had a native version of php previously running and tried to upgrade via brew. When i try and run brew commands I am getting the following.. First I check with the doc:

```
brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

All seems well, but then i run:

```
brew update
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
...
Aborting
Error: Failed to update tap: josegonzalez/php
```

I have looked around and tried a number of suggestions to no avail and keep going in loops here..

Comment: Did you try `brew tap --repair`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so i had the same/similar headaches a while ago. This seemed to work for me, firstly establish where things live:

```
$php -v
$which php
```

This is let you know what your current state is, versions and where things reside.

Regarding the brew issues we need to address the taps:

```
$brew untap josegonzalez/php
$brew update
$brew tap josegonzalez/php
...
$brew update
```

You should then be able to run the following without issue:

```
$brew install php5X
```

Note that i had to run a variation to produce the libphp5.so file that i needed to link to in my httpd.conf

```
$brew install php5X --with-fpm --with-apache
```

After that it was a case of updating the module link in my httpd.conf to something similar to:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php54/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Restart apache with the following and you should be cooking on gas!

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

You can then verify everything with:

```
$php -v
```

and also pop an index.php page in your localhost dir with:

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Double check that the apache and command line versions of php match and you should be good to go!

I also found the whole process easier with the ‘locate’ command which made tracking down certain file locations a lot easier…